# Set TabBar Item badge count with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, swiftui, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Is it possible to show TabItem badge with SwiftUI?

It is easy to achieve with UIKit like described here ->

[How to set badge value in Tab bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044345/how-to-set-badge-value-in-tab-bar)

I didn't find a way to do this with a SwiftUI.
The only possible way is to access to UITabBarController using scene rootViewController and modify its tab bar items directly.

```
  func setBadgeCount(_ count: Int) {
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = count

    guard let delegate = app.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate else {
        return
    }

    if let tabBarController = delegate.window?.rootViewController?.children.first {
      tabBarController.viewControllers?.first?.tabBarItem.badgeValue = "\(count)"
    }
  }
```

Any ideas how to do this with native SwiftUI approach?

Comment: SwiftUI 3 (requiring iOS 15) now has a `.badge` modifier. [See this answer for an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67894115/77567)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, SwiftUI don't have badge feature so we must custom.

Reference [HERE](https://medium.com/@jihad.fayz/swiftui-tutorial-showing-badge-on-tab-bar-item-d71e4075b67a) I create My tabar with badge

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private var badgePosition: CGFloat = 2
    private var tabsCount: CGFloat = 2
    @State var selectedView = 0
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                TabView {
                    Text("First View")
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                            Text("First")
                        }.tag(0)
                    Text("Second View")
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "star")
                            Text("Second")
                        }.tag(1)
                }

                ZStack {
                  Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)

                    Text("3")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 12))
                }
                .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                .offset(x: ( ( 2 * self.badgePosition) - 0.95 ) * ( geometry.size.width / ( 2 * self.tabsCount ) ) + 2, y: -30)
                .opacity(1.0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution you provided! It is a pity Apple didn't add support for tab bar item badges support to SwiftUI.

Comment: It's common feature, I think SwiftUI will support it, maybe in some next version

Comment: If you are compiling for both iPad and iPhone you can replace 0.95 in offset with `(UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone ? 0.95 : 1.65)`

Answer (score 6):

Now in SwiftUI 3 they added a `.badge()` modifier

Source: [HackingWithSwift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-a-badge-to-tabview-items-and-list-rows)

```swift
TabView {
    Text("Your home screen here")
        .tabItem {
            Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
        }
        .badge(5)
}
```

Comment: This only works starting from iOS 15

Answer (score 1):

```
 func calculateBadgeXPos(width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let t = (2*CGFloat(self.selectedTab))+1
        return CGFloat(t * width/(2*CGFloat(TABS_COUNT)))
    }
```

then use it here:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                // make sure to update TABS_COUNT
                TabView(selection: self.$selectedTab) {
                   ...
                }
                
                NotificationBadge(...)
                .offset(x: self.calculateBadgeXPos(width: geometry.size.width), y: -28)
            }
        }
```

Looks sth like this on `Preview`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned .introspectTabBarController modifier worked for me.
Gave a nice native badge on tabItem. Looks great on both orientations.

```
    .introspectTabBarController { (UITabBarController) in
        self.tabBarControl = UITabBarController
        if let items = UITabBarController.tabBar.items {
            let tabItem = items[2] // in my case it was 3rd item
            tabItem.badgeValue = "5" // hardcoded
        }
    }
```

Though, when changing tabs, the **badge disappears** so I saved UITabBarController in @State and when tab changes I set tabItem.badgeValue again.

P.S: iOS 15+ supports .badge modifier. Use it if you're targeting above or iOS 15.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 15 added support for `.badge` modifier, but as I need to support iOS 14, I've created `UITabBarController` wrapper:

```
struct TabBarController<TabContent: View, Tab: Hashable>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let tabs: [Tab]
    @Binding
    var selection: Tab
    let tabBarItem: (Tab) -> UITabBarItem
    let badgeValue: (Tab) -> String?
    @ViewBuilder
    let contentView: (Tab) -> TabContent

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UITabBarController {
        let controller = UITabBarController()
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UITabBarController, context: Context) {
        context.coordinator.viewControllers
            .keys
            .filterNot(tabs.contains(_:))
            .forEach { removedKey in
                context.coordinator.viewControllers.removeValue(forKey: removedKey)
            }
        uiViewController.viewControllers = tabs.map { tab in
            let rootView = contentView(tab)
            let viewController = context.coordinator.viewControllers[tab] ?? {
                let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: rootView)
                viewController.tabBarItem = tabBarItem(tab)
                context.coordinator.viewControllers[tab] = viewController
                return viewController
            }()
            viewController.rootView = rootView
            viewController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = badgeValue(tab)
            return viewController
        }
        uiViewController.selectedIndex = tabs.firstIndex(of: selection) ?? 0
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(selection: $selection)
    }

    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
        @Binding
        private var selection: Tab
        var viewControllers = [Tab: UIHostingController<TabContent>]()

        init(selection: Binding<Tab>) {
            _selection = selection
        }

        func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
            guard let newTab = viewControllers.first(where: { $0.value == viewController })?.key else {
                print("tabBarController:didSelect: unexpected")
                return
            }
            selection = newTab
        }
    }
}
```

`filterNot`:

```
extension Collection {
    @inlinable public func filterNot(_ isNotIncluded: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Element] {
        try filter { try !isNotIncluded($0) }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
TabBarController(
    tabs: [1,2,3],
    selection: $selection,
    tabBarItem: { tab in
        UITabBarItem(title: "tab \(tab)", image: UIImage(systemName: "1.square.fill"), tag: 0)
    },
    badgeValue: { tab in
        "\(tab)"
    },
    contentView: { tab in
        Text("\(tab) screen")
    }
).ignoresSafeArea()
```

Comment: hey Phil! Could you please tell what is `filterNot`? Do you use a custom function there?

Comment: @AlexanderKhitev ah yes, I've added it to my answer - I think `filterNot` makes code more readable, but you can replace it with `filter` too

Answer (score -1):

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        Text("Home")
            .tabItem {
                Text("Home")
            }
        
        Text("Home")
            .tabItem {
                Text("Home")
            }
        
        Text("Home")
            .tabItem {
                Text("Home")
            }
    }
    .introspectTabBarController { (tabbarController) in
        if let items = tabbarController.tabBar.items {
            let tabItem = items[2]
            tabItem.badgeValue = "1"
        }
    }
}
```

}